# Nothing is Eternal

Tags: riddle

What slowly dies when its alive, but lives longest when kept dead?

Hint 1:

> It's a common household object

Comment: Lots of great answers that fit the riddle well!  The answer i was thinking of was iiiidk's

Comment: Yeah there were many great answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What slowly dies when its alive, but lives longest when kept dead?

The first thing that came to mind to me was

> cut flowers: once they are cut, they begin to die. You can only prolong them for a while in a vase. However, if you turn them upside down and dry them properly, they last a very long time (and keep their smell, too!).

Although I believe that isn't the answer we're looking for, so my second idea is

> a candle. It you light one, it begins to melt. You *could* collect all that material and build a new candle, but most people don't bother. However, if you don't light the candle then it remains.... a candle.

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

> A Light Bulb

Explanation:

> When its turned "on" it slowly burns out. It also lasts the longest (lives) if it is never turned "on" (kept dead)

Answer (score 2):

This could be couple of things

> Any type of battery/cell phone, (or a candle/lightbulb as @iiiidk and @wolfram42 said). When these are on they slowly die, but when the device is off, they will hold their charge for wayy longer and live.

Also from another angle:

> You could apply this to rare items. When you use them, they depreciate (die) in value. When they are dead (mint-condition/not in use), their value is sustained/increased (lives).